# Always the same cookie

Tags: express, cookies

I needed a really basic authentication method for a small application on my company. So I started using in-memory signed cookies in the 'cookie-parser' package within express, and it is working just fine.

But playing around with the requests headers I noticed that the cookie is always the same (like id_user=s%3Aj%3A%2bf4d3b4cfc4c44649d68a3%22.C5pKkDOqSZBj%2BRFFvpJb15AVEOVkwGR5oIi), even when it expired and the user has to log in again. This made me feel less secure, because if someone steal that cookie, it can always be used as long the 'real' person is logging in. Is there a simple way to each time the person logs in, it receives a different cookie?

I am using the basic cookieParser, then an auth function as a middleware:

```
import cookierParser from "cookie-parser";

app.use(cookierParser("123321"));

function auth(req, res, next) {
  try {
    if (req.signedCookies.id_user) {
      req.user = {
        name: req.signedCookies.name_user,
      };
      next();
    } else {
      res.redirect("/login");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
}
```

When the user logs in, I am setting an id_user and a name_user cookie(to show the name of the user in the web view).

And so:

```
router.get("/verySecurePath", auth, (req, res) => {
  res.render("verySecurePage.html", {
    name_user: req.user.name,
  });
});
```

Comment: signed just means signed, if its same data it would be the same value

Comment: Got it. Alternatives?

Comment: Alternatives to what? I think your mistaking cookies for a security layer, signedCookies are simply for preventing tampering. If you use http only over SSL you can prevent the cookies being stolen.. is the same issue with JWT, if poorly served and handled then a XSS could allow for the cookie/token to be stolen and used.

Comment: In some web sites I use, each time I log in, I get a different cookie, is it possible to achieve that in express, how?

Comment: sure, put a timestamp in the value alongside the name_user but it won't achieve much

Comment: little example on https://glitch.com/edit/#!/express-cookies to show the diff

Comment: This works, invalidates past cookies, right?
Appreciate your help, Lawrence, thanks!
You can answer the question to organize.